# How to write JSON using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have two text box T1 and T2.
I need to save that two values as json in separate file using java script.
my target is to write values in separate file and have to retrieve later.
please guide me how to write json in separate file..thanks in advance.

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: What do you mean "in separate file"? You want to transmit the JSON to your web server and have server-side code write it to a file? (JS in the browser can't access the local file system.)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:
https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

View its readme file here:
https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/README

Comment: To be more direct, https://raw.github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/master/json2.js is what you want